# Adding one record at a time in a many to many relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities "User" and "Team" in my Symfony2 project. 
User can have many teams and a Team can have many users.

The way I'm adding players to a team now is through a selectbox (with all the users in it from the database) where the user can select many users and click save to insert it into the database.

I would like to have two textboxes instead of a selectbox, because I don't like the logged-in user to be able to see all the available users (especially when this box would get very long)

How can I do this?
So, 2 textboxes (with a jquery autocompleter that I will add) and a save button to add the 2 users to the team.

Thx.

Edit:

```
<?php

namespace Tennisconnect\DashboardBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class TeamType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('player_one', 'text', array('property_path' => false))
            ->add('player_two', 'text', array('property_path' => false))
        ;  
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'team';
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array('data_class' => 'Tennisconnect\DashboardBundle\Entity\Team');
    }
}
```

ChallengeType:

```
<?php

namespace Tennisconnect\DashboardBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class ChallengeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('teams', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new TeamType(),
                'allow_add' => true
            ))
            ->add('place')
            ->add('date');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'challenge';
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array('data_class' => 'Tennisconnect\DashboardBundle\Entity\Challenge');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the user related field and add two unbound fields to your `TeamType`, eg.

```
$builder->add('new_member_1', 'text', array('property_path' => false))
        ->add('new_member_2', 'text', array('property_path' => false));
```

That will display two textfields in your rendered form. Then write some logic in your controller that reads these fields, fetches the users and add them to your team.

```
// ... controller action
// first bind request
$form->bindRequest($request);
if ($form->isValid()) {
   // fetch first username
   $username = $form->get('new_member_1')->getData();
   $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('YourBundle:User')->findOneByUsername($username);
   $team->addUser($user);
   // same for second user
}
```

This is a minimalistic example. So you need to add some validation, error handling etc, but it shows how it might work for you.

**Edit:**

If you have nested form types, you can walk through the elements by *getting down the path* to your child.

```
$form->get('outer_type')->get('team_type')->get('new_member_1')->getData();
```

Comment: thx for the answer :) this is what I was looking for. But how would I fetch the data from the textfields in the controller when the team-form is embedded in another form?

Comment: I have this now: $username = $form->get('teams')->get('player_one')->getData(); What should I put instead of 'outer_type'? I think the property in the Challenge entity? Or rather TeamType? Both options are giving me an error.

Comment: outer_type was just an example. If you have have just to types (the "main" form and your team form) just leave it away. If you need more help, please add your form types to you questions.

Comment: It's telling me it cant find the field 'player_one'

Comment: Hmm, you are using the collection type. I don't really know how to access the values of collections. But maybe you want do redesign your form. An option would be to move the players to your ChallengeType (replace the add('teams'...) with the two add('player_*') lines and access them by $form->get('player_*')) or change 'collection' to new TeamType() and remove the options array. Than you can access the fields by $form->get('teams')->get('player_*).

Comment: thx for the comment hacksteak25 ... i'm going to look for a solution using the collection, because it would be nice to let that work. But if I can't find out how, then I'll replace the collection :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fetched the data from the collection:

```
foreach($form->get('teams') as $team_form) 
{
    $player_one = $team_form->get('player_one')->getData();
    $player_two = $team_form->get('player_two')->getData();
}
```